# Reading a web form's name/value pairs in Python

Tags: python-3.x, webforms, stdin

I am collecting data on a web form and using AJAX to send the name/value pairs to a python script.

```
<form id="myForm">
Name: <input type="text" name="uName"><br>
Phone: <input type="text" name="uPhone"><br>
</form>
```

Script:

```
var cgiString=$("#myForm").serialize();
$.ajax({                
    url: "cgi/test.py",             
    dataType: "json",       
    date: cgiString,
    type: "post",           
    error: ajaxError,           
    success: function(json){    
       // handle returned JSON  
    }
});
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to read the data in test.py.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sqlite3
import cgi
import json
import io

# read from stdin ?

# parse out name and phone ?

# return JSON
```

I assume it's just reading from STDIN (how?). Then I need to parse out the name/value pairs. Is there a python module to do this?

Answer (score 0):

the answer was to use **cgi.FieldStorage()**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
uName=form["uName"].value
```